# Jenkins Subversion Tagging a single module

Tags: svn, jenkins, tags

I am checking out SVN code from 2 different repositories, so in Jenkins, I am using Multiple Module to check out my branches from 2 different repos. On a successful build I want to tag only one branch of a repository.

The problem here is, the Subversion Tagging Plugin doesn't have any option to choose the repo I want. (I am using the `svn copy` command for now) Are there any other solutions available, perhaps as Jenkins plugins?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subversion Tagging Plugin, by Default Tags all the Module you loaded into the Configuration page, However, it uses the Below ENV variables to Identify the Repos like,

SVN_REVISION_1:nnnnn

SVN_REVISION_2:nnnnn

SVN_URL_1:http//hostname/repo1/branches/foo1/foo2

SVN_URL_2:http//hostname/repo2/trunk/roo1/

Used the Relative Tagging Concept,
" ../tags/${env['JOB_NAME']} "

Ref: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Subversion+Tagging+Plugin

However, I corrected the Dept of the Folders in SVN_URL_n to maintain equal Leveling between urls.